# Javascript setTimeout guaranteed call order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

```
setTimeout(funcA, 0)
this.setState() //react async call
setTimeout(funcB, 0)
```

For the code above, is the order of execution guarenteed to be `funcA` > update to this.state > `funcB`?

AFAIK, Javascript has no multi-threading, hence asyn calls are simply pushed into a queue. Is this just a FIFO queue or a priority queue?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: no ... this.setState -> funcA -> funcB - because asynchronous code waits for no man

Comment: how does `setState` work? Does it not get pushed to the queue like `funcA`?

Comment: The only thing that's guaranteed here is that `this.setState` will be invoked first, before either `funcA` or `funcB`. You invoke `this.setState()` immediately while `setTimeout()` defers the invokation of those functions until the thread is idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout()` with 0ms as argument is a way to defer a task when the call stack empties out.

What that means is that while the following code is executed:

```
setTimeout(funcA, 0)
this.setState() //react async call
setTimeout(funcB, 0)
```

1. `funcA` is added to the task queue
2. `this.setState` is add to call stack and immediatelly executes and returns
3. `funcB` is added to the task queue

So only `this.setState()` is immediately invocked and `funcA`, `funcB` will be added in the *ordered* task queue, so they will be invocked *in order*.

As I understand this, from the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue) it is a FIFO queue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot depend on ordering of micro-tasks. If you want to enforce order, and assuming `funcA` is synchronous, then

```
setTimeout(() => {
  funcA();
  this.setState().
    .then(funcB);
});
```